# Getting redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI error in facebook login with jsf

Tags: facebook, jsf

I am trying to integrate facebook login with my website. Here is my some part of the code:

```
public void socialConnect() throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("graph.facebook.com.consumer_key", "561379830565954");
    props.put("graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret", "883e8d729d0358b4040fbffa762d832d");
    props.put("graph.facebook.com.custom_permissions", "publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location,offline_access");
    SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();
    config.load(props);
    manager = new SocialAuthManager();
    manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String successURL = externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/socialLoginSuccess.xhtml";
    String authenticationURL = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(providerID, successURL);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(authenticationURL);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 191
  }
}
```

What should be the redirecct_uri? How can i fix it can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `redirect_uri` has to be a fully qualified URL with the protocol (`http(s)://`), domain, path, etc.

If you're writing a desktop application, according to [How to login / authenticate facebook without browser for desktop application in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062084/how-to-login-authenticate-facebook-without-browser-for-desktop-application-in) there is not explicit support for desktop applications, but there is a workaround (and it's outlined in that question).

Comment: I added http:// but still the same error. What should i add more, can you give me an example please?

Comment: If this isn't a web app (which I guess was silly to assume), you'll probably have to follow a different authentication process. editing answer

Comment: if it is a web app,then what is the actual value of `successURL`?

Comment: it returns localhost:8080/BankApp/socialLoginSuccess.xhtml where BankApp is the name of my application

Comment: I did like this,  String successURL = "http://"+externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "socialLoginSuccess.xhtml"; is that fine? Still does not work

Comment: Try encoding your `successURL` so it looks like this: `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FBankApp%2FsocialLoginSuccess.xhtml`

Comment: thanks but i did not understand what you said. What should i do to encode it?

Comment: It's a URL encoded value, it's possible that whatever SDK you're using to create your authentication URL doesn't encode (escape) your success URL, which could be causing the browser to not send the entire URL accurately, which could cause FB to see an invalid URL. Here's a SO question about encoding URIs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198894/java-encode-url

Comment: hey i solved the problem it looks like externalContext.getRequestContextPath() already returns a "/" and so i have http:///. Thank you so much